How to make end of line draw match the node at the end of another line
I would like to represent a camera placed on the ceiling with a rectangular node and lines representing the focus of the camera. The code is as follows:
\documentclass[border=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage    {tikz}
\usepackage    {siunitx} 
\usetikzlibrary{calc, positioning, fit}    

\begin{document}
    
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
        lineBlk/.style={draw=black, line width=0.75mm,},
        blockCAM/.style={draw=black, line width=0.75mm, 
            fill =lightgray!60,
            inner sep=1em, 
            outer sep=0em, 
            % fill=red!70, rounded corners,text =white,
            minimum width=1.4cm,
            minimum height=0.8cm,} 
        ]
    
        \node[blockCAM] (CAM) at (0,5) {};
        \draw[lineBlk] ($(CAM.south west)!0.5!(CAM.south)$) --++ (250:0.6cm)  node[outer sep=0] (cam1) {} ;
        \draw[lineBlk,] ($(CAM.south)!0.5!(CAM.south east)$) --++ (-70:0.6cm) node[outer sep=0] (cam2) {} -- ($(cam1)+(-0.0mm,0)$) ;
    
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}


The second line drawn does not end at the node of the first line drawn. I have tested line cap=rect, line cap=round and inner sep=0 and outer sep=0, but the two bottom corners of the focus are not equal. Besides, I would like to fill the focus area with a color.
I would like to draw the entire focus shape with one \filldraw, but I do not know how to center the focus relative to the body of the camera.

Ending a line withcycle fixes the angles edges.

Why don't you draw this as a closed path?

You could use a single path:
\documentclass[border=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage    {tikz}
\usepackage    {siunitx} 
\usetikzlibrary{calc, positioning, fit}    

\begin{document}
    
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
        lineBlk/.style={draw=black, line width=0.75mm,},
        blockCAM/.style={draw=black, line width=0.75mm, 
            fill =lightgray!60,
            inner sep=1em, 
            outer sep=0em, 
            % fill=red!70, rounded corners,text =white,
            minimum width=1.4cm,
            minimum height=0.8cm,} 
        ]
    
        \node[blockCAM] (CAM) at (0,5) {};
        \draw[lineBlk] ($(CAM.south west)!0.5!(CAM.south)$) --++ (250:0.6cm) -- ($(CAM.south)!0.5!(CAM.south east)+(-70:0.6cm)$) -- ($(CAM.south)!0.5!(CAM.south east)$) -- cycle;
    
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}



Thank you, very clever solution.

@pablo You're welcome!
